# excel , extract the time Break from one cell in excel sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet like below and I need only the three *"Break"* times even if it meant to delete every thing except those three Breaks in every cell.

[image: excel sheet like this]

```
Function GetBreaksTime(txt As String)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Split(txt, "Break")
    If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
        ReDim startTimes(1 To UBound(arr)) As String
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            startTimes(i) = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(Split(arr(i), "-")(0), vbLf, ""))
        Next
        GetBreaksTime = startTimes
    End If  
End Function
```

This what I got until now but it wont work on every cell and it takes wrong values.

So any idea how to do this?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ how to make the output  by row not column ?
how to make it run on the all the 7 cells of the week ?

Comment: Please be more precise. Make what by row?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ how to make the output side by side like                                                  
         4:15PM- 4:30PM  5:45PM- 6:15PM  9:45PM-10:00PM
not under each other?

Comment: i mean how to run on a range for example  `(CellValue = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("c2:i2").Value`

Comment: You must loop through the columns of row 2. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split the cell value by `vbLf` the break time will always follow a line containing `"Break"`.

The following should work:

```
Sub TestGetBreakTimes()
    Dim CellValue As String
    CellValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

    Dim BreakTimes As Variant
    BreakTimes = GetBreakTimes(CellValue)

    Debug.Print Join(BreakTimes, vbLf)  'the join is just to output the array at once.

    'to output in different cells loop through the array
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(BreakTimes)
        Cells(3 + i, "A") = BreakTimes(i)
    Next i

    'or for a even faster output use
    Range("A3").Resize(UBound(BreakTimes) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(BreakTimes)
End Sub

Function GetBreakTimes(InputData As String) As Variant
    Dim BreakTimes() As Variant
    ReDim BreakTimes(0)

    Dim SplitArr As Variant
    SplitArr = Split(InputData, vbLf) 'split by line break

    If UBound(SplitArr) > 0 Then
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To UBound(SplitArr)
            If SplitArr(i) = "Break" Then 'if line contains break then next line is the time of the break
                If BreakTimes(0) <> vbNullString Then ReDim Preserve BreakTimes(UBound(BreakTimes) + 1)
                BreakTimes(UBound(BreakTimes)) = SplitArr(i - 1) 'collect break time
            End If
        Next i
        GetBreakTimes = BreakTimes
    End If
End Function
```

To analyze a complete range you must loop through your row 2

```
Sub GetAllBreakTimes()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim BreakTimes As Variant

    Dim iCol As Long
    For iCol = 1 To LastCol
        BreakTimes = GetBreakTimes(ws.Cells(2, iCol).Value)
        ws.Cells(3, iCol).Resize(UBound(BreakTimes) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(BreakTimes)
    Next iCol
End Sub
```

Comment: but it gave for the first cell 
4:30PM- 5:45PM,,,,
6:15PM- 9:45PM,,,,
10:00PM-11:00PM,,,,
and i need
4:15PM- 4:30PM,,,,
5:45PM- 6:15PM,,,,
 9:45PM-10:00PM,,,,

Comment: Then use `SplitArr(i - 1)` instead of `SplitArr(i + 1)`.

Comment: nice one last question  how to get the result in different cells?

Comment: Do this in the sub (eg `TestGetBreakTimes`) by looping through the array (see updated code)